# Open source sdk for face recognition android offline

Tags: android, sdk, camera, face-recognition

i am new to android. Now i am working on face recognition android application. Can you please suggest me the best sdk which is open source and doesn't have any legal issues if it is used as an open source. I request your suggestions & support. Thanks one and all.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

For face recognition on android try to use OpenCV SDk.

OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision Library) is an open source computer vision and machine learning software library. The library contains algorithms that can be used to detect and recognize faces, identify objects, classify human actions in videos, track camera movements, track moving objects, extract 3D models of objects, and etc.

Follow the given instructions in this link: http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html.

Comment: Dennis, just for the info, while suggesting link, make sure you include brief about it or necessary information otherwise it would become a link-only answer and people may vote it for close.